# Dependencies not found for service when using npm link and npm run start:dev

Tags: express, service, dependency-injection, request, nestjs

I have a module that I'm developing locally.  When I use `npm link` in the module and then in my nest project `npm link myModule` then `npm run start:dev` my project fails to start with this error.
`Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuditLogService (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.`
However, when I have the module published and use standard `npm i` everything works great.
Things I've tried:

- Service/provider is correctly added to `app.module.ts`'s providers
- Ensured that common dependencies in package.json have the same versions.
- `npm i myModule` makes everything work after I've published.

Thoughts:

- my service is scoped for the request but it's failing during startup, is this the culprit?

Artifacts:

- Startup script `"start:dev": "ts-node-dev --inspect --require tsconfig-paths/register --require dotenv/config server.ts"`
- Service:

```
import { transformAndValidate } from 'class-transformer-validator';
import { Inject, Injectable, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';
// @ts-ignore
import { Request } from 'express';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { DFDHeaders, AuditLogEntry } from '../dtos';
import axios, { AxiosResponse, AxiosError } from 'axios';
import _ from 'lodash';
// @ts-ignore
import logger from 'dfd-logger';
import { AuditLogResponse } from '../types/audit-log';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class Service {

  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST)
  {
    protocol,
    hostname,
    originalUrl,
    headers
  }: Partial<Request>) {
    ...
  }
...
}
```

- Dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^6.3.2",
    "@nestjs/core": "^6.3.2",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^6.1.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.0.4",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/chance": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.133",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.0",
    "chance": "^1.0.18",
    "class-transformer": "^0.2.3",
    "class-transformer-validator": "^0.7.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.9.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "6.4.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/testing": "6.1.1",
    "@types/express": "4.16.1",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.11",
    "@types/nock": "^10.0.3",
    "@types/node": "11.13.4",
    "@types/supertest": "2.0.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.13.0",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^22.13.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "husky": "^3.0.1",
    "jest": "24.5.0",
    "nock": "^10.0.6",
    "prettier": "1.18.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.3",
    "supertest": "4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^24.0.2",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.40",
    "tsconfig-paths": "3.8.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever found a way to make this work?

Comment: not that I can remember and I no longer have access to that repository.

Answer (score 0):

I no longer have access to that repository so I couldn't tell you if I fixed it or repro it locally.